# How to mock REST server before Spring context initialization?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I have a Spring Bean that sends a request inside its constructor using `RestTemplateBuilder` in order to send a request:

```java
@Service
class MyService {

  MySettingsFromRemote settings;

  MyService(RestTemplateBuilder builder, @Value("${my-url}") String url){
    var rt = builder.build();
    setting = rt.getForEntity(url, MySettingsFromRemote.class);
  }
  
  ...
}
```

During testing, I would like to mock the response using `MockRestServiceServer` (or maybe mock the `RestTemplateBuilder` that is used to send the request) with some predefined data just so the application context loads. The address is written in the `application.properties` file.

I tried doing this:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.AutoConfigureMockRestServiceServer;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers;

import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockRestServiceServer
@SpringBootTest
public class CollectorApplicationTest {
    
    @Autowired
    MockRestServiceServer server;
    
    @Value("${components.web-admin-portal.rest.schemas}")
    String webAdminPortal;
    
    @Before
    public void init() {
        
        server.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(webAdminPortal))
              .andRespond(withSuccess("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        
    }
}
```

But the context loads before the `@Before` method is executed and fails with a message saying the `MockRestServiceServer` didn't expect the request.

Then I tried using `ApplicationContextInitializer`:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers;

import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess;

public class AppInit implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(final ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        
        context.refresh();
        MockRestServiceServer server         = context.getBean(MockRestServiceServer.class);
        String                webAdminPortal = context.getEnvironment()
                                                      .getProperty("components.web-admin-portal.rest.schemas");
        
        server.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(webAdminPortal))
              .andRespond(withSuccess("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}
```

But then it complains that the `MockServerRestTemplateCustomizer has not been bound to a RestTemplate`. I figured that this issue may be resoled by using `@RestClientTest` annotation on the test class since it would disable auto configuration of `RestTemplateBuilder` and enable confiration of `MockRestServiceServer`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@RestClientTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AppInit.class)
public class CollectorApplicationTest {
```

But it did not change anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at my old question in 2021, I'd do it differently now.

It seems I needed to get some settings from a remote server like this (pseudo code below):

```java
@Service
class MyService {

  MySettingsFromRemote settings;

  MyService(RestTemplateBuilder builder, @Value("${my-url}") String url){
    var rt = builder.build();
    setting = rt.getForEntity(url, MySettingsFromRemote.class);
  }
  
  ...
}
```

So, instead of doing that, I'd reorganize the code like this:

```java
@Service
class MyService {

  MySettingsFromRemote settings;

  MyService(MySettingsFromRemote settings){
    this.settings = settings;
  }
  
  ...
}


@Configuration
class MyConfig {

  // maybe Spring provides this bean now?
  // rest template is kinda outdated already, webclient is preferred.
  @Bean RestTemplate myRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
  }

  @Bean MySettingsFromRemote mySettingsFromRemote(RestTemplate restTemplate, @Value("${my-url}") String url){
    return restTemplate.getForEntity(url, MySettingsFromRemote.class);
  }
}
```

Then it's very easy to test. Just need to provide a `@MockBean` of `MySettingsFromRemote`.

Answer (score 3):

this setup works for me:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public MyService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        //make your call here
        restTemplate.getForEntity("http://www.localhost:9090", String.class);
    }

}
```

This make the call when and only when the spring context is fully initialized

and in test classes:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class MockServiceCallConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Bean
    public MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer() {
        MockRestServiceServer server = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

        server.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo("http://www.localhost:9090"))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        return server;
    }
}

@SpringBootTest(classes = {MockServiceCallConfiguration.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {


    @Test
    public void test() {

    }

}
```

It's pretty tedious, if you can refactor your code and avoid calling rest service during initializiation setup but rather on some business event, it would surely be better

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow and provide an update, thanks for the idea!

Comment: @Sam no problem let me know

Comment: Not sure what that changes. `@PostConstruct` executes right after the constructor, so absolutely nothing has changed

Comment: @Sam sorry it seems that I misunderstood your use case, I publish a new solution. I saw that you find your own one, pick the best for you

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer! I cannot refactor the code because the application must get some settings from another component via HTTP in order to be able to function, so placing it on startup is necessary. Also, you're using `RestTemplate` while I use `RestTemplateBuilder`, so that's a bit different. I will think about moving the request to the listener method, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a way (if anyone has a better solution, please, leave another answer). `@RestClientTest` does a this that is pretty close to what is needed in this case but not enough. We need `RestTemplateBuilder` to always generate the same `RestTemplate`, and we also need a `MockRestServiceServer` that is bound to that `RestTemplate`. I did that by replacing `RestTemplateBuilder` Bean definition with a mock and also preconfigured the `MockRestServiceServer` right in the bean definition to make sure that this code executes before any requests are sent.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CollectorApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class A {

        @Primary
        @Bean
        public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder(@Value("${components.web-admin-portal.rest.schemas}")
                                                               String webAdminPortal) {

            RestTemplate          restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            MockRestServiceServer server       = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
            server.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(webAdminPortal))
                  .andRespond(withSuccess("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

            RestTemplateBuilder mockBuilder = mock(RestTemplateBuilder.class);
            when(mockBuilder.build()).thenReturn(restTemplate);
            return mockBuilder;
        }
    }
}
```

That way application starts successfully.